# Sending email from Drupal contact form, but GMail marks it as "Forged"

Tags: drupal, drupal-contact-form

My Drupal site sends email to a GMail account, but the emails sent all go into the Spam folder, and GMail puts up a bar with the message "This message was likely forged and did not originate from your account."

Although I can create a filter to prevent them going to Spam, I want to start sending newsletters, and I suspect they'll have the same problem.

I suspect the problem is with the way I've set up either PHP or Drupal to send mail. As far as I know it's just using the sendmail function. I've set the from address to "info@..." where ... is the site domain. Any tips on how I can make set up my outgoing mail so it won't be refused by GMail (and presumably other major mail providers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this article to get you on the right track.
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That looks like the source of my problem, particularly the reverse DNS lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps I followed to get my Drupal emails working. The solution will be different for you depending on which services you're using, but hopefully this will give you a starting point.

1. In my web host admin area (cpanel), I created an email address for my domain (admin@xxxxx.com).
2. In my web host admin area (cpanel), I created an email forwarder so that emails sent to this address will be forwarded to my gmail account.
3. In the settings for my gmail account, under "Accounts and Import", I chose "Add another email address" and added my domain email address. See [this link](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/free-smtp-server/#settings_saved) for details on how to do this. This allows my gmail account to send emails using my domain address as an alias.
4. In Drupal, I installed the [SMTP Authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module. In the configuration for this module, I used the same SMTP information that I used in step 3 to set up my gmail alias.
5. Now Drupal can send authenticated messages from my gmail account that claim to be from admin@xxxxx.com.